# Visual Studio Code indentation tab size of 2 spaces ignored on format (in Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting, indentation

I want to use 2 spaces for indentation in Visual Studio Code (version 1.38.1) for Python (Other languages as well but for now Python). However, when auto formatting (on save and using Shift Alt F) it changes it to 4 spaces.

I have set it up so that 2 spaces are used and I can see this in my settings and in the
[bottom right hand corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1NZM.png).

Here are my settings:

```
{
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light",
    "editor.codeLens": false,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

I have also updated the config.py file

```
prefs['indent_size'] = 2
```

I have  3 extensions, Python, C# and yo.

I have trawled the internet to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have the program set to indent with tabs, not spaces. That is why your change is not working. Try clicking the `Tab size: 2` and select `Indent Using Spaces`. Does that work?

Comment: Are you using the Python extension? And if so what formatter did you set up?

Comment: @HampusLarsson no it did not work :(

Comment: @BrettCannon I am using Python extension for Visual Studio Code. I don't remember setting up a formatter, do you know where I could check this?

Comment: @bardr the Python extension doesn't provide formatting without you setting it up (unless VS Code is magically using `"editor.formatOnType"` somehow to apply to the whole file, in which case it isn't using "editor.tabSize".

You can check your settings by looking at your `.vscode/settings.json` file in your workspace or opening your settings in VS Code. (And `config.py` has nothing to do with the Python extension for VS Code so I'm not sure what that's meant for.)

Answer (score 1):

None of the formatters supported by the Python extension to my knowledge read VS Code's setting for formatting. You will need to configure the formatter directly to have it keep a 2 space indent (which will vary from formatter to formatter, including not even being configurable if you chose black).